# Select encoding while writing a CSV file in pypark

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, encoding, pyspark

I am trying to set the proper encoding while saving a CSV compressed file using pyspark.

Here my test:

```
# read main tabular data
sp_df = spark.read.csv(file_path, header=True, sep=';', encoding='cp1252')
sp_df.show(5)
+----------+---------+--------+---------+------+
|      Date|     Zone|   Duree|     Type|Volume|
+----------+---------+--------+---------+------+
|2019-01-16|010010000| 30min3h|Etrangers|   684|
|2019-01-16|010010000| 30min3h| Français| 21771|
|2019-01-16|010010000|Inf30min|Etrangers|  7497|
|2019-01-16|010010000|Inf30min| Français| 74852|
|2019-01-16|010010000|   Sup3h|Etrangers|   429|
+----------+---------+--------+---------+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

We can see that the data was properly interpreted by using the encoding CP1252. The problem is that when I save the data in a CSV gzipped file using the CP1252 encoding and checking it back, the special characters are not well decoded:

```
# Save Data
sp_df.repartition(5, 'Zone').write.option('encoding', 'cp1252').csv(output_path, mode='overwrite', sep=';', compression='gzip')

# read saved data
spark.read.csv(os.path.join(output_path, '*.csv.gz'), header=True, sep=';', encoding='cp1252').show()
+----------+---------+--------+---------+------+
|      Date|     Zone|   Duree|     Type|Volume|
+----------+---------+--------+---------+------+
|2019-01-16|010070000| 30min3h|Etrangers|  1584|
|2019-01-16|010070000| 30min3h|FranÃ§ais| 18662|
|2019-01-16|010070000|Inf30min|Etrangers| 12327|
|2019-01-16|010070000|Inf30min|FranÃ§ais| 30368|
|2019-01-16|010070000|   Sup3h|Etrangers|   453|
+----------+---------+--------+---------+------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Any ideas?
I am using spark 2.3

Answer (score 2):

According to [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv), encoding is an option you should put directly in the `csv` method the same way you use it for read.

```
sp_df.repartition(5, 'Zone').write.option('encoding', 'cp1252').csv(output_path, mode='overwrite', sep=';', compression='gzip')
```

to become

```
sp_df.repartition(5, 'Zone').write.csv(output_path, mode='overwrite', sep=';', compression='gzip', encoding='cp1252')
```

The way you wrote it is overwritten by the default argument of the `csv` method `encoding=None` which leads to a UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I have this error while putting the encoding parameters inside the csv() method:
`TypeError: csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`

And when I try the method:
`sp_df.repartition(5, 'Zone').write.option('sep', ';').option('encoding', 'cp1252').mode('overwrite').format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option('codec', 'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec').save(output_path, header = 'true')`
I still have the default 'utf-8' encoding applied while saving the file...

Comment: @oso_ted there is obviously a problem with your `csv` method because you should not receive the error `TypeError` you describe. `encoding` is a [legit argument for this method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv). Do you still get the same encoding without using the compression ?